# Finding the second max element in a binary search tree

Tags: c++, max, binary-search-tree

I have a problem with finding the second maximum element in a binary search tree.
I do not know why but in some cases my programm crashes or gives incorrect answer (I don't know those cases).
Help me to find a problem in my algorithm in code below. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    struct Node {
        Node* right;
        Node* left;
        int data;
        Node* parent;
    };

    Node* maximum(Node *root){
        if (root -> right)
            return maximum(root -> right);
        else
            return root;
    }
    void insert(Node *root, Node *a){
        if (root -> left && root -> data > a -> data)
            return insert(root -> left, a);
        if (root -> right && root -> data < a -> data)
            return insert(root -> right, a);
        if (root -> data > a -> data){
            root -> left = a;
            a -> parent = root;
        }
        if (root -> data < a -> data){
            root -> right = a;
            a -> parent = root;
        }
    }
    int main(){
        int j = 0;
        int n = 0;
        Node *root = new Node;
        cin >> j;
        if (j != 0) {
            root -> data = j;
            root -> parent = NULL;
            root -> left = NULL;
            root -> right = NULL;
        } else {cout << "0"; return 0;}
        while (true){
            cin >> j;
            if (j == 0) break;
            Node *a = new Node;
            a -> data = j;
            a -> left = NULL;
            a -> right = NULL;
            a -> parent = NULL;
            insert(root, a);
        }
if(!max -> parent)
    if (max -> left)
        cout << maximum(max -> left) -> data;
    else
        cout << max -> data;
else
    if (max -> left && max -> left > max -> parent)
        cout << maximum(max -> left) -> data;
    else
        cout << max -> parent -> data;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There are a lot of [awfull error-prone pointerland] non-question related code here. Simplify the snippet.

Comment: And please run your code in a debugger and tell us on which line the crash occurs.

Comment: I tested this code in judge system and don't know at what input it crashes, so I can't debug it.

Comment: @Porfiriy You're developing on some sort of PC, right? Then please compile it on that machine and debug it there before posting it onto any kind of online system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code:

```
Node* max = maximum(root);

if (max->left){
    if (max->parent->data > max->left->data) cout << max->parent->data;
    else cout << max->left->data;
} else
    cout << max->parent->data;
```

If your `max` turns out to be `root`, then `max->parent` will be `NULL`. So you should check for `NULL` condition before testing it on `data`.

Comment: I've added it and now I got 52 test (48 before), but there are still cases in which my programm doesn't work as it should.

Comment: This is because of the wrong logic you are using. I don't want to tell you the exact solution, but as a hint, you are second max will be in the left subtree of `max` or its parent. If its in left subtree, you cannot find it with a simple `if-else` but you need to traverse the left subtree.

Answer (score 0):

Check you are following this Logic :-

Second max will be in the left subtree of max or its parent.

If if left-subtree exists then find max of left-subtree which is second highest

If if left-subtree does not exist then parent of max is second highest.

Corner cases

1) root is null i.e. no element. No need to check all these.

2) Root is the only element i.e. there is only 1 number. So no second highest as parent of root is null.